# Does Molex SlimStack round cable jumper exist?

Tags: jumper

Today I learned the following connectors are a SlimStack plug and receptacle.

However, I only found flex cables jumpers, [like this one](https://www.arducam.com/product/b0186-arducam-imx219-sensor-extension-cable-raspberry-pi-nvidia-jetson-nano/). Is there a reason round cables don't exist for this sort of connector?

I would need something like that for a project, as flex cables are not as freely movable as round cables.

[image: Molex SlimStack]

Comment: round doesnt merge easily into big and flat

Comment: That's understandable. However, some sort of adapter would exist maybe?

Comment: Like a little PCB you made yourself? heh

Comment: Well I would if I had the knowledge to do it. The project I am working on would be way easier with a rounded cable.